# Change DAG owner

Tags: airflow

I want to change DAG owner, but I don't want to use

```py
default_args={'owner': 'someone'}
```

**This method doesn't guarantee user validation.**

So I made my custom plugin with WTForms (two field: dag_name, dag_owner), but the owner changes back to **airflow** after some time.

Function that updates owner of the dag:

```py
def update_dag_owner(dag_name: str, dag_owner: str, session: Session = None):
    session.query(DagModel).filter(DagModel.dag_id == dag_name).update(
        {'owners': dag_owner}
    )
    session.commit()
```

**This code works, but after some time the owner changes back to airflow.** Could you tell why does this happen and maybe some ideas to configure owners of DAGs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow has a service called `DagFileProcessorManager` which list the dag files each `dag_dir_list_interval` and creates a [DagFileProcessor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dagfile-processing.html) instance for each file. This `DagFileProcessor` run the python script to create the Dag instance, serialize it, and update old serialized dag in the Metastore if it has a different hash.

When you update the owner using your plugin, you change the serialized dag in the Metastore, but Airflow `DagFileProcessor` recreates the dag from the script with the default owner `airflow` and override you changes.

If you don't want to define the owner as a hard value in dag script, and you want to set it using an http request, you can create a new table `dags_owners` in Airflow Metastore and store the owners there, then read the owner in your dag file from this table:

```py
def update_dag_owner(dag_name: str, dag_owner: str, session: Session = None):
    # add the owner of your dag to the new table (dag_id, owner)
    ...
    # update the owner of your dag to see the change immediately
    session.query(DagModel).filter(DagModel.dag_id == dag_name).update(
        {'owners': dag_owner}
    )
    session.commit()
```

dag:

```py
def get_dag_owner(dag_id):
    # check if the owner is defined in the new table
    owner = ...
    if owner is not None:
        return owner
    return "airflow"
    
default_args={'owner': get_dag_owner(dag_id)}
```